# Viewing cl.exe response file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Visual Studio (2005/2008/2010) appears to create a response file containing flags for the C/C++ compiler, cl.exe.  As soon as compilation finishes, the response file is deleted.

Is there a way to force Visual Studio not to delete the response file?  Is there some other way to view the contents of the response file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the compiler option "Suppress Startup Banner" to "No". This will print out the compiler's options.

Another way to get the content of the file is by suspending the `cl` process while it is running (for example using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)). Then you have time to look at the response file.